# Gitlab CI maven generate sources fails with 400

Tags: maven, gitlab

I'm trying to have our maven builds generate sources and store in the gitlab artifact repo.

Added the following to the POM:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

When I run gitlab CI, the build creates the artifacts (including the regular jar and the sources jar):

```
[INFO] Installing /builds/xxxxx/yyyyy/target/xxxxx-2.2.jar to /root/.m2/repository/com/xxxxx/2.2/xxxxx-2.2.jar 
[INFO] Installing /builds/xxxxxxx/pom.xml to /root/.m2/repository/com/xxxxx/yyyy/2.2/xxxxx-2.2.pom 
[INFO] Installing /builds/xxxxxx/yyyyyy/target/xxxxx-2.2-sources.jar to /root/.m2/repository/com/xxxxxx/yyyyyy/2.2/xxxxxx-2.2-sources.jar
```

Maven then deploys the artifacts, but fails when deploying the sources artifact:

```
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxx/packages/maven/com/yyyy/zzzzz/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxxx/packages/maven/com/yyyyyy/zzzzz/maven-metadata.xml (659 B at 418 B/s)
Uploading to gitlab-maven: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxx/packages/maven/com/yyyyy/zzzzz/2.2/xxxxxxx-2.2-sources.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  33.828 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-09T00:48:16Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project forte-client: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xxxxxx:yyyyyyy:jar:sources:2.2 from/to gitlab-maven (https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxxx/packages/maven): Transfer failed for https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/xxxxx/packages/maven/com/xxxxx/yyyyyy/2.2/xxxxxxx-2.2-sources.jar 400 Bad Request -> [Help 1]
```

If I remove the maven-source-plugin, then the build works fine.

This happens if I run Maven locally, or via Gitlab CI.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and I was searching for a solution. After some (try-fail)s,  the only solution that is working for me was to enable duplicate packages from <group | package> Settings > Packages & Registries > Package registry. Hope it'll work for you too

Comment: Ugh - this is a real shame.  Because allowing duplicates is a really good way to wind up with an artifact getting overwritten by accident if the developer doesn't bump the version.

Have you come up with a workaround for this?  I was hoping that the Exception Regular Expression would be helpful, but I haven't found a setting that works (i.e. ".*-SNAPSHOT|.*-sources" still results in a failure.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior was fixed in GitLab 13.12:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/321772

I've verified that SNAPSHOT artifacts are excluded from the duplicate checking with the following regex, which was used by the developer on the above ticket to validate his fix:

`.*SNAPSHOT.*`

Comment: The issue is about generating a sources artifact in addition to the main jar.  This still fails in latest version of GitLab (hosted - 15.3.0-pre) - definitely not fixed in 13.12

Comment: @KevinDay, thanks for pointing that out. I glossed right over the sources jar.